# Lucene index and Windows DFS replication

Tags: lucene, microsoft-distributed-file-system

I want to replicate Lucene index on my web servers periodically. Apart from Solr, can I setup DFS replication on my Windows 2008 servers and use that to replicate my indexes over my load balanced web servers? Will that approach work or I will have to write parallely to 2 different indexer locations within my crawler code?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure of your question. You cannot have two writers writing to the same location no matter what file system you use. So if you want each of your NLB servers to write to the same location, no, that probably won't work.

If you just have one writer and want to replicate its results across many servers, that will work, but it will probably be quite a bit slower (one of the major Lucene recommendations is to not use networked file systems).